# When a reporter of a newspaper takes some pictures from something and puts them within their newspaper

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

In the following self-made scenario I need to know whether the bold part is natural or there is a better way to mention that:

> But still, Noah is thinking about the girl who **he** met 14 years earlier, a girl he loved like no other, and he is content to live with only memories.
>
> Soon, he finishes restoring the old house in the best way possible **in the manner that newspapers took some pictures from the house and put in their newspapers.**
>
> A newspaper article about his endeavor catches Allie's eye, and 14 years after she last saw Noah, Allie returns to him.

I am sure there is a better way to say that in English; I wonder if you give me a hand with it and let me know about it.

Comment: You could replace the bolded part with "... then the press becomes interested and publishes pictures/photographs of the house." (preserving the adjacent tense used)

Comment: It's not really idiomatic, although it's also not entirely clear what you want to say.  Why would a newspaper take a picture of his house?  Is it architecturally interesting?  Of historical note?  Is he famous enough that people would want to know how he lives?  Such a thing is not really a routine event, outside of some specialty publications.

Comment: Not only architecturally but also because of all the endeavor and the amount of all difficulties that Noah sustained during several years @Andrew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be recast as

> Soon, he finishes restoring the old house in the best way possible. The project attracts attention for its architectural merit, and for the years of effort which Noah had expended. Articles about the project, with pictures, are published  in newspapers.

A qualifying word, such as 'local" or "regional" could be placed before "newspapers".

The original sentence

> Soon, he finishes restoring the old house in the best way possible in the manner that newspapers took some pictures from the house and put in their newspapers.

has some problems. "Manner" should mean a method or style of finishing the house, but "manner that newspapers took some pictures" doesn't really make sense to me. "took some pictures from the house" ought to mean taking pictures looking out of the house, or from the point-of-view of the house, but that seems unlikely. I suspect that  "took some pictures **of** the house" conveys the intended meaning. "and put in their newspapers" should be  "and put **them** in their newspapers. "newspapers took some pictures" is at least award. The pictures were probably taken by reporters or photographers working for the newspapers, and this is compounded by the later "their newspapers". The antecedent of "their" must be "newspapers" leaving "newspapers put pictures in their newspapers" which just doesn't work. Changing the first "newspapers" to "reporters", or recasting to a passive form not saying **who** took the pictures (such as "pictures were taken and published"), avoids this problem, as does my more drastic rewrite above.